# Exercise Connection In Imacro

Tags: javascript, file, imacros

So I'm using iMacros and I will use a JS file to play my macro and in sometimes in random times jump to me a exercise connection like this:

"answer the exercise 10+5=" and I have to write the corrent answer.

like this:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=TH ATTR=TXT:2+4=

and I want to create var the worth the result of the exercise.

can I create bot that do it by imself?

Comment: You can use .js and .split() method. Then you can get those numbers and operations (- + * /) and make .js code recognize those.

Comment: can you show me how to do that?

Comment: Search javascript imacros on stack